# Change group title in radgridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgridview

When i group be default the `radgridview` by Telerik The name of the column and the value of the cell are put it like the title of the Group

```
{Column Title}: {Cell Value}
```

[image]

But I need to change that to have just the `{Cell Value}`

Is any way to do that with C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about removing the pre-fixed column names from the values after grouping, you can subscribe to the `GroupSummaryEvaluate`event, and then override the default formatting.

For example, if your column names are "Rotulo" and "Termino", as it appears in your example:

```
void radGridView_GroupSummaryEvaluate(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.GroupSummaryEvaluationEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.SummaryItem.Name == "Rotulo") || (e.SummaryItem.Name == "Termino"))
    {
        e.FormatString = e.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```